# How to connect closest keypoints (blobs) with a line?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, line

I'm trying to draw a (straight) line passing through black spots (on a binary threshold image). I tried without success and now think using the keypoints in the blobdetector is a good option.

How can you connect the keypoints from detected blobs in a binary threshold image? Maybe by connecting the *closest* blobs together with a line? And maybe later on by removing the *lines* that are below a minimum length?

Image with blobs detected:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That might be a good use case for the plain [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform), i.e. OpenCV's [HoughLines](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga46b4e588934f6c8dfd509cc6e0e4545a) method.

Here's what my approach does (I used a cropped, grayscaled version of your first image):

- Inverse binarize the input image to have white points on black background. (The less white, the faster the Hough transform.)
- First Hough transform with high accumulator threshold to obtain the main angle of the resulting lines by finding the median.
- Second Hough transform with fixed main angle, but lower accumulator threshold to get also the shorter lines (bottom right corner).
- Group neighbouring lines.

First, let's have a look at the output. That's after the first Hough transform:

[image: After first Hough]

You can see, most lines have the "right" angle, but not all. After the second Hough transform with the fixed angle, but lower accumulator threshold, we get (output not reflected in below code):

[image: After second Hough]

All desired lines are detected, but there are sets of neighbouring lines. After grouping them, the final output would look like this:

[image: Final result]

And, here comes the whole code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


# Draw lines using rho and theta values
def draw_lines(image, rhos, thetas):
    for i in np.arange(thetas.shape[0]):
        a = np.cos(thetas[i])
        b = np.sin(thetas[i])
        x0 = a * rhos[i]
        y0 = b * rhos[i]
        pt1 = (np.round(x0 + 1000 * -b).astype(np.int32), np.round(y0 + 1000 * a).astype(np.int32))
        pt2 = (np.round(x0 - 1000 * -b).astype(np.int32), np.round(y0 - 1000 * a).astype(np.int32))
        cv2.line(image, pt1, pt2, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    return image


# Read image, convert to grayscale and inverse binarize
img = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.png')
_, img_thr = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY), 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# First Hough transform with high accumulator threshold
lines = cv2.HoughLines(img_thr, 1, np.pi / 180, 200)

# Just for visualization: Intermediate output
img_hough1 = draw_lines(img.copy(), lines[:, 0, 0], lines[:, 0, 1])

# Get main angle
main_theta = np.median(lines[:, 0, 1])

# Second Hough transform with mediocre accumulator threshold, and fixed angle
lines = cv2.HoughLines(img_thr, 1, np.pi / 180, 100, min_theta=main_theta - 0.01, max_theta=main_theta + 0.01)

# Group remaining lines
rhos = np.sort(lines[:, 0, 0])
line_idx = np.where(np.diff(rhos) > 100)[0]
new_rhos = []
s = 0
for i in np.arange(line_idx.shape[0]):
    e = line_idx[i]
    new_rhos.append(np.mean(rhos[s:e + 1]))
    s = line_idx[i] + 1
    if i == line_idx.shape[0] - 1:
        new_rhos.append(np.mean(rhos[s:rhos.shape[0] + 1]))

# Final output
img_hough2 = draw_lines(img.copy(), new_rhos, np.ones_like(new_rhos) * main_theta)

# Output visualization
cv2.imshow('img_hough1', img_hough1)
cv2.imshow('img_hough2', img_hough2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hope that helps!

---

Disclaimer: The line drawing code was adopted from [this OpenCV tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d5/df9/samples_2cpp_2tutorial_code_2ImgTrans_2houghlines_8cpp-example.html).

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful and your notes are appreciated.
Concerning the Group Remaining Lines is this actually really merging or just a ''visual trick'' ? Because when I'm printing len(lines) the result is not coherent (printing around 30 in the above example)

Comment: @Gil I don't update `lines`. Actually, `new_rhos` and `main_theta` describe the new lines. So, `len(new_rhos)` should reflect the number of (new) lines.